# Не билдится проект на АНдроид на Unity 2019.4.19f1

Tags: android, unity3d

Не билдится проект, прогуглил кучу сайтов, но ничего не работает. Можете помочь и если возможно,  то с самыми подробными инструкциями[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По пути к проекту есть русские символы?

Comment: попробуйте переустановить android sdk, java sdk и прочие дополнения для билда на андроид

Comment: UserGames а как это проверить?

Comment: Покажите третью ошибку полностью